# How to check AccuRev license validity

Tags: accurev

How can I check the license validity for the Accurev installed.
I just want to view the date when it is going to expire. Tried google, but it didnt help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are logged onto the server, just open the license file and look at the expiration date.

The file is found under "accurev install directory/storage/site_slice".  Depending on the version of AccuRev you are using, the license file is called keys.txt or accurev.lic.

Answer (score 1):

In the license file, you will see two dates. The first date is the license expiration date and typically, it is "permanent", meaning the license is perpetual. The second date is the maintenance date. This will not allow you to upgrade to a version of AccuRev that was built after the maintenance date.